# How to merge new index in old index by replacing some documents

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I am trying to merge the lucene indexes using java program.
 My requirement is to replace the already having files and merge the new files for it I am using the following code .

```
try{
    File INDEX_DIR= new File("path of first directory");
   INDEX_DIR.mkdir();
   File indexDir = new File("path of first directory");
  Directory indexes[] = new Directory[indexDir.list().length];
   IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(
   FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR),
   new SimpleAnalyzer(),true,
  IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED); 

 indexes[0] = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);

writer.addIndexes(indexes[0]); 

File indexDir1 = new File("path of second directory");
Directory indexes1[] = new Directory[indexDir1.list().length];

indexes1[0] = FSDirectory.open(indexDir1);

writer.addIndexes(indexes1[0]);
writer.optimize();
  writer.close();   
  System.out.println("index merged");
 }
```

catch(Exception ex)
    {

```
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Are you running into a particular problem with this code?